# Check out issue with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Whenever I press F7 on any UI form, form file is being Checked Out for edit which shouldn't be the case. Not sure how to rectify this issue.

Please suggest!

Comment: If you allow it to check it out does it make any changes to the file? Can you do a comparison with source control and verify?

Comment: It doesn't make any changes in the code. It only checks out.